# Desktop icons get messed up with dual monitors after boot

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors and everytime I start the computer the icons get squashed together under the left pane to the very edge of the screen, see the print screen. Sometimes they get moved to the second monitor, which is not my main monitor. The monitor number one is my main screen. I have GeForce GTX 970 GPU and NVIDIA drivers installed.
[image: desktop][image: monitors]

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates. The problem started 1,5 month ago when I connected another monitor to the computer.